# for loop not working in unit testing in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am running a Simple Django Unit test of my model(User) to check the type of attribute of my model. I have a username attribute which is of CharField.
When I am running the below code it showing my test case passed with no errors and also the username is not getting printed, which is inside the for loop as following.

```
 class UserModelTest(TestCase):
      def test_fields(self):
          ob=User.objects.all()
          for object in ob:
              print(object.username)
              self.assertIsInstance(object.username,int)
```

I think the output should be an error since I am checking with an Integer type and the usernames should get printed.

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You didn't create any users within the test to iterate over.